# WPF datagrid cell textbox control

Tags: wpf, textbox, textchanged, datagridcell

I have datagrid cell and under that I have a textbox control. How do I call text changed event of that textbox control using routed event?
I tried EventSetter but it's not working.

here is code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DatagridCellWithTextbox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtCell" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" TextChanged="">                                
                        </TextBox>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
     </Style>
```

Thanks
Dee

Comment: can you pls provide answer why you gave -1 vote.

Comment: Probably because you ask almost same question again.

Comment: pls provide me link where I have asked Q of this situation.

Comment: Okay, it looks almost same, but it wasn't me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCell" TextChanged="txtCell_TextChanged">
```

and it is working. You gave your style a `x:Key`. Have you applied the style?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DatagridCellWithTextbox}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```